# converting for loop to while loop

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code. can anybody tell me how to change the inner loop to a while loop.

```
import turtle 
import time   
wn= turtle.Screen() 
alex= turtle.Turtle() 
alex.hideturtle() 
alex.pensize(5) 
list= [['alex.left(90)','alex.forward(200)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.right(90)','alex.forward(75)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.right(90)','alex.forward(55)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.penup()','alex.goto(65,136)','alex.pendown()','alex.circle(10)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.penup()','alex.goto(75,127)','alex.pendown()','alex.goto(75,98)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.right(90)','alex.forward(30)','time.sleep(1)','alex.goto(100,98)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.penup()','alex.goto(75,98)'], 
['alex.pendown()','alex.left(90)','alex.forward(45)','time.sleep(1)'] 
,['alex.right(120)','alex.right(180)','alex.forward(50)','time.sleep(1)'], 
['alex.penup()','alex.goto(74.00,51)','alex.pendown()','alex.right(120)','alex.forward(45)','alex.left(120)']] 
for items in list:
  for sublist in items:
     exec(sublist) 
  wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Could you maybe tell us why you would want to do that?

Comment: The `for` loop processes every single element of an array. Here's a wild guess, the OP wanted to only process some of the elements. Is that what you intend to do @user3558932?

Answer (score -1):

It's not entirely clear what you want, however you could consider using the :

```
while True:
```

It would then **infinitely** loop until you either exit the program, or use:

```
break
```

An example from the Python docs is:

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")
    if n.strip() == 'hello':
        break
```

You could essentially put what you currently have into the loop:

```
while True:
    for items in list:
        for sublist in items:
            exec(sublist) 
        wn.exitonclick()
```

However without the exit, or break, this would loop **continuously**.

Comment: This just wraps the current code in a `while True`, that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: The explanation wasn't very clear, I assumed they just wanted the inner loop (assuming it was the `for` loop) to loop continuously... I don't see any point of converting it to a while otherwise